# Write a custom access operator in Swift

Tags: swift, operators

I implemented a helper to have an array of unowned references:

```
class Unowned<T: AnyObject>
{        
    unowned var value : T    

    init (value: T) { self.value = value }
    func get() -> T { return self.value }
}
```

Now, it is possible to do `[ Unowned<Foo> ]`. However, I'm not satisfied with having the additional `get()` method to retrieve the underlying object. So, I wanted to write a custom binary operator, e.g. `-->` for being able to do

```
for unownedFoo in ArrayOfUnownedFoos
{
    var bar : Int = unownedFoo-->method()
}
```

My current approach is to define

```
infix operator --> { }
func --><T> (inout lhs: Unowned<T>, inout rhs: () -> Int) -> Int
{
}
```

The idea I had behind this is:

1. lhs is obvisouly the object I get out of the array, on which I want to perform the call on
2. rhs is the method I desire to call. In this case `method()` would not take no parameters and return an `Int`, and therefore
3. The return value is int.

However, the following problems / uncertainties arise:

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. Are my assumptions above correct?
3. How can I call the provided closure `rhs` on the instance of the extracted `Unowned<T>`, e.g. (pseudocode) `lhs.value.rhs()`. If `method()` was static, I could do `T.method(lhs.value)`, but then I would have to extract the name of the method somehow to make it more generic.

Comment: In your candidate code for `-->` you used `Int`, did you mean `T`?  Or a second type parameter, say `V`?

Comment: That is because I refer to the return type of method. Of course, in a more generic version this should be another generic type e.g. `V` respectively the return type of the called method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, a postfix operator is rather simple.

```
postfix operator * {}

postfix func *<T>(v:Unowned<T>) -> T {
    return v.value
}

// Usage:
for unownedFoo in ArrayOfUnownedFoos {
    var bar : Int = unownedFoo*.method()
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer that, because it is more flexible IMO. I also tried it at first, but forgot to add `.` for the call and then the compiler complained that `*` is not a binary operator, which brought me to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
func --> <T:AnyObject, V> (lhs: Unowned<T>, rhs: (T) -> V) -> V
{
   return rhs (lhs.get())
}
```

and then use it as:

```
for unownedFoo in ArrayOfUnownedFoos
{
    var bar : Int = unownedFoo-->{ (val:Int) in return 2*val }
}
```

Specifically, you don't want to use `method()` as that itself is a function call - which you probably don't want unless `method()` is actually returning a closure.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. Ideally, I'd like to use the methods name directly, but a closure is a sufficient workaround.